# Python - convert each row in columns in a specific way

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have some data like shown below.

```
Group   Item1   Value1  Item2   Value2  ……so on Val10
 A      apple     2     pears     -4    
 B      orange   -5     banana     3    
 C      grapes    6     apple     -8    
 D      pears     8     orange     1
```

What I want to do is generate only 2 columns as Item and Value and put all the row information in those columns like below.

```
Group   Item     Value
 A      apple      2
 A      pears     -4
 B      orange    -5
 B      banana     3
 C      grapes     6
 C      apple     -8
 .       .         .
 .       .         .
 .       .         .
```

I tried searching for solutions and also tried things with df.melt, pd.pivot_table but could not achieve the desired result. Could you please help ? :)

Comment: `pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['Item', 'Value'], i='Group', j='_')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your columns are properly named with a numeric suffix, you can use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
>>> (pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['Item', 'Value'], i='Group', j='id')
       .droplevel('id').reset_index())

  Group    Item  Value
0     A   apple      2
1     B  orange     -5
2     C  grapes      6
3     D   pears      8
4     A   pears     -4
5     B  banana      3
6     C   apple     -8
7     D  orange      1
```

Comment: this worked, I had to change the col names to series as you said. thanks :)